# How to print Array type data from console to mobile screen in React Native

Tags: react-native, api, rest, pagination, response

[image: This is the response data from api]

i want to add pagination in screen with this response , tried different tutorials but didn't solve my problem. i updated my Question and add code where i am stuck in this problem .

```js
fetch(`api`,{ 
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        // setData([responseJson])
        setData([...data, ... responseJson.data]);
        console.log("log for blogs =====>", responseJson.result)
        console.log("blogs:::: =====>", responseJson.result)

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });

  }
```

````
const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.itemRow} >


        <Text style={{fontSize:20}}>{item.publisher}</Text>
        <Text style={{fontSize:40}}>{item.short_description}</Text>

      </View>
    )
  }

  return (
    <FlatList
      style={styles.container}
      data={data}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    />

  )```
````

Answer (score 1):

First of all, i think that will be great if you explain a little more about you dataset and you final objective.

In React Native, I usualy use `<FlatList>` to render a data list. (https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist)

The data props is you dataset, and the renderItem is the output for each data "row".

```
<FlatList
    data={DATA}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
/>
```

I noticed that your dataset contains some HTML contents. If you want to render this on this list, you'll have some issues, case the sintax its different.

**Edit 1 - Based on the question edit:**

I still not undestending whats is the actual problem you are facing. The state is not being updated ? Just the new data is seted ? The FlatList is not beeing updated ?

I think that what you want is to "append" the new response data to you state, right ?

If is that what you want, you are in the right way. Maybe you're having problems when using the "data" state inside you function. What about this:

```
setData(prev => [...prev, ...responseJson.data]);
```

`prev` is the state data, basicaly the same of `data`, but idepends of scopes like useCallbacks or useEffects

Comment: I update my question . please go through it

Comment: I edited my answer, you can check if this solves it

Comment: Glad to read that. If possible, select the answer that solved your problem (or most helped with) for further people with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Edit based on the question edit:

it seems like you are setting responseJson.data in your state instead of responseJson.result.data

try this

```
setData([...data, ...responseJson.result.data])
```

Comment: I update my question and add some code where i am stuck. please go through it